# How to write omit function with proper types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What I ultimately want to do is to create a React HOC that would inject a property defined by a string and return a component without requiring the injected property. In essence though this boils down to a factory function returning an omit function.

As you can see in this example for some reason the type B ends up being 'never'.

```
const f = <A extends object, B extends keyof A>(arg: B) => (obj: A): Omit<A, B> => {
  delete obj[arg]
  return obj
}
// TS2345: Argument of type "test" is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
const a = f('test')
const b = a({ test: 1})
const c = b.test
```

When I try keyof outside of generic parameter, it seem to be functioning better, but typescript does not infer the return type properly and I do not know how to type it as I do not know how to get the reference to the first string arg that could be used in Omit:

```
const f = <A extends object>(arg: keyof A) => (obj: A) => {
  delete obj[arg]
  return obj
}
const a = f('test')
const b = a({ test: 1 })
// Does not infer 'test' is no longer here
const c = b.test
```

For reference Omit is:

```
export type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first function has both type arguments, typescript will try to infer both when that call happens and since there is no inference site for `A` it will probably infer `{}` for it, making `B` never. The way to fix this, is to make `B` and when the second call occurs infer `A`, with the constraint that `A` must have a `B` key:

```
export type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

const f = <B extends keyof any>(arg: B) => <A extends Record<B, any>>(obj: A): Omit<A, B> => {
delete obj[arg]
return obj
}

const a = f('test')
const b = a({ test: 1, other: ""})
const c = b.test; // error as expected
const c2 = b.other; // ok
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps tremendously. I realised thought I have one more piece in the HOC, that I omitted in the question. Would it be possible to back propagate the `A` type somehow to the first function call. What I want to do is `<B extends keyof any>(arg: B, fn: (arg: A) => void) => ...`. So basically, I give you attribute name and a function that will take object I will give you later. If that does not make sense I can create new question, my bad I did not realise this will be important.

Comment: @aocenas could you post a new question with the full code ? It would make more sense to see it in full.. the comments is not a good place for a lot of code..

Comment: Here is the new question, hope it makes sense https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470559/back-propagate-type-inference-when-currying-in-typescript