# Back propagate type inference when currying in typescript

Tags: typescript

I hope the title makes sense. What I want to do is to have a factory function that takes a function taking an argument which will be supplied in later call of the returned function. In essence:

```
const f = <B extends keyof any>(arg: B, fn: (props: A) => void) => <A extends Record<B, any>>(obj: A): Omit<A, B> => {
  fn(obj)
  delete obj[arg]
  return obj
}
```

Obviously `A` is not available to the first function definition and it has to be in the second function definition to be inferred properly (see my previous question [How to write omit function with proper types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466131/how-to-write-omit-function-with-proper-types-in-typescript)).

I assume there could be at least a way to constrain `A` to both `A extends Record<B, any>` as that is needed so that the first arg is actually a key from the object supplied later, while at the same time it has to be the same as the `fn` props.

The example is contrived but in essence something similar should be needed for redux connect style HOC. Issue is I do not understand redux type definitions enough to know how to take them and modify for my usecase.

EDIT:
Example of the HOC I want to create:

```
export const withAction = <A extends keyof any, B extends object>(
  actionName: A,
  // The B here should actually be OuterProps
  actionFunc: (props: B, ...args: any[]) => Promise<any>,
) => <InnerProps extends object, OuterProps extends Omit<InnerProps, A>>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<InnerProps>,
): React.ComponentType<OuterProps> => {
  return (props: OuterProps) => {
    // This is a react hook, but basically it just wraps the function with some
    // state so the action here is an object with loading, error, response and run
    // attributes. We just need to wrap it like this to be able to reuse hook
    // as a HOC for class based components.
    const action = useAction((...args) => {
      // At this moment the props here does not match the function arguments and
      // it triggers a TS error
      return actionFunc(props, ...args)
    })
    // The action is injected here as the actionName
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...{ [actionName]: action }} />
  }
}

// Usage:
class Component extends React.Component<{ id: number, loadData: any }> {}
// Here I would like to check that 'loadData' is actually something that the
// component want to consume and that 'id' is a also a part of the props while
// 'somethingElse' should trigger an error which it does not at the moment.
const ComponentWithAction = withAction('loadData', ({ id, somethingElse }) =>
  API.loadData(id),
)(Component)
// Here the ComponentWithAction should be React.ComponentType<{id: number}>
render(<ComponentWithAction id={1} />)
```

Comment: Could you also  add an expected usage example? If `fn` already has the type baked in then it's simple.. but the function returned `f` would only be usable for a specific `A`...

Comment: I added the full HOC I am working on, I hope it clears things up.

Comment: It helps you added your HOC, I will try to have a look, but can't promise I'll get to it today ... maybe someone else will answer before :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir don't worry you already helped me a lot.

Comment: If you call `foo(x).bar(y)` there's no way for the compiler to use the type of `y` to infer a type parameter needed by `foo()`.  This becomes especially clear if you assign the intermediate thing to a variable `const foox = foo(x);` and then later call both `foox.bar(y)` and `foox.bar(z)`.   The type of `foox` is set before `foox.bar(y)` or `foox.bar(z)` is called.  And if it weren't, which of `foox.bar(y)` or `foox.bar(z)` decide the type of `foox`?  Both?

Comment: @jcalz You are right I just wasn't sure whether there isn't some way as TS still surprises me sometimes. I answered the question with update of the code, with which I am happy enough right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I managed to partially do what I want and I think it is probably only thing that is possible here as mentioned by @jcalz in a comment.

In the general example:

```
// Adding '& C' to second generic params
const f = <B extends keyof any, C extends object>(arg: B, fn: (props: C) => void) => <A extends Record<B, any> & C>(obj: A): Omit<A, B> => {
  fn(obj)
  delete obj[arg]
  return obj
}
const a = f('test', (props: { another: number }) => {})
// TS error, another: number is missing which is good
const b = a({ test: 1 })

const d = a({ test: 1, another: 1 })
// test does not exist which is good
const c = d.test
```

And in the HOC example:

```
export const withAction = <A extends keyof any, B extends object>(
  actionName: A,
  actionFunc: (props: B, ...args: any[]) => Promise<any>,
) => <
  InnerProps extends object,
  // The only change is here that OuterProps has '& B'
  OuterProps extends Omit<InnerProps, A> & B
>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<InnerProps>,
): React.ComponentType<OuterProps> => {
  return (props: OuterProps) => {
    const action = useAction((...args) => {
      return actionFunc(props, ...args)
    })
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} {...{ [actionName]: action }} />
  }
}

// Usage:
class Component extends React.Component<{ id: number; loadData: any }> {}
const ComponentWithAction = withAction(
  'loadData',
  // somethingElse here does not trigger the error which would be nice but
  // probably not possible
  (props: { id: number; somethingElse: number }) => API.loadData(props.id),
)(Component)
// Here the ComponentWithAction is React.ComponentType<{id: number, somethingElse: number }>
// and so TS correctly errors that somethingElse is missing
render(<ComponentWithAction id={1} />)
// This is correct but strangely some Webstorm inspection thinks loadData is
// required and missing here. So far first time I see Webstorm trip with TS.
render(<ComponentWithAction id={1} somethingElse={3} />)
```

So this seem to be type safe enough and correct for my usecase, my only nitpick is that I would like to have the type error in the actionFunction instead of having it in the component usage later on. Probably not possible but I will leave this open for some time to see if there is nobody who would know a way.